# Code Works When Using F8 but Not When Run Fully

Tags: excel, vba, office365

First of all I'm not very good at Excel macro.
After going through multiple forums, I managed to come up with a code to Crop images in a folder using Excel VBA.

the code opens up each image in Excel, paste in a chart, crop the image, resize to match the height & width and then replace the original image with the edited image.

Macro is working fine with F8 but when I run the macro fully, Images are not getting replaced with the edited one, instead it's replacing with blank image.
After digging through multiple options, the only conclusion I came up with is the macro is running fine in Excel 2013 but it's not running properly with office 365.

Can anybody help me, how to resolve this or have any better code to run?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()
    Dim XL As Object
    Dim thisPath As String
    Dim BooksPAth As String
    BooksPAth = "C:\Images\" 
    
    thisPath = ActivePresentation.path
    
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        
    Run "Crop_vis", BooksPAth   
End Sub
```

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()
    Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not (Shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Or Shp.Type = msoFormControl) Then Shp.Delete
    Next Shp
End Sub
```

```
Sub Crop_Vis(ByVal folderPath As String)
    Dim Shp As Object, path As String, sht As Worksheet, s As Shape, TempChart As String
        'Dim folderPath As String
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
        If folderPath = "" Then Exit Sub

        Set sht = Sheet1
        sht.Activate
        sht.Range("A10").Activate
        path = Dir(folderPath & "\*.jpg")
        
        Do While path <> ""
            DeleteAllShapes
            Set Shp = sht.Pictures.Insert(folderPath & "\" & path)
            ' Use picture's height and width.
            Set s = sht.Shapes(sht.Shapes.Count)
            s.PictureFormat.CropTop = 50
            s.Width = 768
            s.Height = 720
            
            'Add a temporary chart in sheet1
            Charts.Add
            ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=sht.Name
            Selection.Border.LineStyle = 0
            TempChart = Selection.Name & " " & Split(ActiveChart.Name, " ")(2)
              
            With sht
                'Change the dimensions of the chart to suit your need
                With .Shapes(TempChart)
                    .Width = s.Width
                    .Height = s.Height
                End With
                    
                'Copy the picture
                s.Copy
                    
                'Paste the picture in the chart
                With ActiveChart
                    .ChartArea.Select
                    .Paste
                End With
                
                'Finally export the chart
                .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export fileName:=folderPath & "\" & path, FilterName:="jpg"
                'Destroy the chart. You may want to delete it...
                .Shapes(TempChart).Cut
            End With

            path = Dir
        Loop

        DeleteAllShapes
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: When asking about a problem with your code, it helps to include your code in your post.

Comment: Sorry about that.. i have added the code now

Comment: Try between `.ChartArea.Select` and `.Paste` to add the following line `Do While Application.Ready = False: DoEvents: Loop`

Comment: Thank you . 
I tried adding the same. But it didn't worked

Comment: Does it help if you replace `.ChartArea.Select` with `.Parent.Activate`?

Comment: no luck with this either. Images are still coming as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
'Finally export the chart
```

insert something like this, to make sure that pasting of the image into the chart has finished:

```
Do
    If ActiveChart.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the pasting. When you tell it to paste the clipboard (image) into the chart, sometimes it ignores you. When you go to export the chart, you end up with an empty image.

It's not that you have to wait for it to paste, because it's not going to - it ignored you. I have no idea why it ignores you, or why it doesn't error out when it ignores you - it just ignores you with no warning. Maybe Windows is just too busy under the hood to paste.

Basically, what you have to do is check to see if it pasted, and if not, paste again....and again....until it finally sees fit to process your instruction.

I debugged, Googled, trialed and errored and banged my head on the wall for week on this and finally ended up with this:

```
Sub SavePictureFromExcel(shp As Shape, SavePath As String)
    Dim Imagews As Worksheet
    Dim tempChartObj As ChartObject
    Dim ImageFullPath As String
    
    Set Imagews = Sheets("Image Files")
    Set tempChartObj = Imagews.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, shp.Width, shp.Height)
    shp.Copy
    tempChartObj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'No Outline
    tempChartObj.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse 'No Background
    
    Do
        DoEvents
        tempChartObj.Chart.Paste
    Loop While tempChartObj.Chart.Shapes.Count < 1
    
    ImageFullPath = SavePath & "\" & shp.Name & ".png"
    tempChartObj.Chart.Export ImageFullPath, Filtername:="png"
    tempChartObj.Delete
End Sub
```